# I am trying to write a function that returns the value for a gapper estimate of scale of a dataset. Can someone take a look?

Tags: python, math, statistics, astropy

If you don't care about context and just want to look at the code, skip down two paragraphs.

I am working on a project where I am measuring velocity dispersions of galaxy clusters, given galaxy redshift data collected from our group's telescope at the south pole (SPT). For clusters that have very few member galaxies, typical estimators such as the standard deviation or even a more sophisticated biweight dispersion is not sufficient.

Wainer & Thissen (1976) propose an interesting estimator of scale which considers the gaps between data in its measure of the dispersion, which they show to be very effective for data sets of small sizes (93% at n = 10)

Here is the definition:

[image: gapper estimator]

where *n* is the sample size, and

[image: gaps], the gaps between the data points

[image: weights], a set of approximately Gaussian weights, and

[image: range]

Its pretty straightforward, but I am trying to implement it in Python and keep getting the wrong answer. Answers that are way too small. I can't see anything wrong with it though, I've inspected nearly everything. Does anyone see a subtle syntax error that I'm missing or something? Here is the function:

```
def gDispersion(v):
    # Returns the gapper velocity dispersion of a cluster (Sigma_G), given galaxy proper velocity data,
    # v is an array of velocity values.

    try:
        #allocate array for Gaussian weights
        w = [0] * (len(v)-1)
        g = [0] * (len(v)-1)
        n = len(v)
    except TypeError:
        # ensure input is valid
        print('Array or array-like object expected; got {}'.format(type(v)))
        return

    # find gaussian weights
    for i in range(len(v) - 1):
        g[i] = v[i+1] - v[i]
        w[i] = i * (n - i)

    sigG = (np.sqrt(np.pi))/(n*(n-1)) * sum([wi*gi for wi,gi in zip(w,g)])
    return sigG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weights are wrong. In the loop `i` takes the values `0, 1, ..., n-2`, so

```
w[0] = 0, w[1] = 1*(n-1), ..., w[n-2] = (n-2)*2
```

The loop is also unnecessary. Here is a vectorized implementation:

```
def gDispersion(v):
    """ Returns the gapper velocity dispersion of a cluster (Sigma_G)

    v is an array of galaxy velocity values.
    """
    n = len(v)
    w = np.arange(1, n) * np.arange(n-1, 0, -1)
    g = np.diff(v)
    sigG = (np.sqrt(np.pi))/(n*(n-1)) * np.dot(w, g)
    return sigG
```

By the way, use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) instead of comments to document your functions.

Comment: You probably want `(np.sqrt(np.pi))/(n*(n-1)) * np.sum(w * g)`.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks so much. I've been switching to and from Matlab and python a lot lately so I commonly make mistakes when expecting zero indexing when I shouldn't or vice verse :P I'm going to change this now and if it's all good I'll mark this as answered

Comment: Hm. Its still drastically wrong in the output. It must be a flawed understanding that I have, must be using it in the wrong way. As far as this function goes, I think it is correct.